# Hide / Remove Specific GoogleMapsOverlay From Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, deck.gl

I have used geojson files into google map by multi selection . but when i try to remove overlay , it is not working .this is my code to used for add and remove.
i need to know **how to remove selected geojson file from map**

```
    var deckOverlay ;
    deckOverlay = new deck.GoogleMapsOverlay({
                layers: [
                    new deck.GeoJsonLayer({
                        id: 'layerId',
                        data: 'path of geojson file',
                        filled: true,
                        pointRadiusMinPixels: 2,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        pointRadiusScale: 2000,
                        getFillColor: f => (f.properties.COLOR),
                        wireframe: true,
                        pickable: true,
                    }), +
                    new deck.ArcLayer({
                        id: 'arcs',
                        data: Layer_Id,
                        dataTransform: d => d.features.filter(f => f.properties.scalerank < 4),
                        getSourcePosition: f => [-0.4531566, 51.4709959], // London
                        getTargetPosition: f => f.geometry.coordinates,
                        getSourceColor: [0, 128, 200],
                        getTargetColor: [200, 0, 80],
                        getWidth: 1
                    })
                ]
            });   

    if (checked) {
        deckOverlay.setMap(map); // Set multiple overlays working
    }
     else {
        deckOverlay.setMap(null); // Remove Option Not Working
        deckOverlay = null; 
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Data Layer to overlay Geojson? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

Comment: yes i used it but when i try to remove layer it is not worked . 'map.data.remove(Layer_Id);'

Comment: @LuisTavares thanks for suggestion i solved issue and posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Data Layer .

**To load map**

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(Layer_Id);
```

**To Remove Specific Layer**

```
map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
if (feature.getProperty('myprop') == myprop) { 
map.data.remove(feature);
}
});
```

**To Remove All Layers**

```
map.data.forEach(function (feature) { 
map.data.remove(feature);
});
```

*FYI , use color codes as HEX in json file not RGB or RGBA*